# Yii CDbCommand can not read data from table

Tags: mysql, yii, phpexcel

I use PHPExcel to read cells from Excel and write it into mysql table.
Then I use a CDbCommand to get records from the table.
But somehow the CDbCommand failed to get records.
The records are there in the table, the sql statement is correct, but the CDbCommand failed to get the record.

I test the sql statement build by CDbCommand and run it on mysql workbench and it get the record.

There is no query error, no syntax error.

Any idea?

Comment: You'll need to show us some code, please. It is hard to diagnose out of thin air.

Comment: It will be helpful if you Show your query.

Comment: database schema and the query please :D

Comment: Could you please update this question with your code samples. Hard to provide an answer without seeing your attempt.